# How to fill a Python numpy chararray with spaces?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, char

For some reason I'm struggling to initialize a `numpy.chararray` with spaces.

This works:

```
char_array1 = np.chararray((3, 3))
char_array1[:] = 'a'
char_array1
```

Output:

```
chararray([['a', 'a', 'a'],
       ['a', 'a', 'a'],
       ['a', 'a', 'a']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

This doesn't:

```
char_array2 = np.chararray((3, 3))
char_array2[:] = ' '
char_array2
```

Output:

```
chararray([['', '', ''],
       ['', '', ''],
       ['', '', '']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

What is causing this? I can't see an option to strip the items or something.

Comment: From `help(chararray)`: The `chararray` class exists for backwards compatibility with Numarray, it is not recommended for new development. Starting from numpy1.4, if one needs arrays of strings, it is recommended to use arrays of `dtype` `object_`, `string_` or `unicode_`, and use the free function in the `numpy.char` module for fast vectorized string operations.

Answer (score 3):

In fact char arrays do remove whitespace:

> Versus a regular NumPy array of type str or unicode, this class adds
>   the following functionality:
>
> values automatically have whitespace removed from the end when indexed
>   comparison operators automatically remove whitespace from the end when
>   comparing values vectorized string operations are provided as methods
>   (e.g. endswith) and infix operators (e.g. "+", "*", "%")

So the answer is use a regular array of type str or unicode:

```
char_array3 = np.empty((3, 3), dtype='str')
char_array3[:] = ' '
char_array3
```

Output:

```
array([[' ', ' ', ' '],
       [' ', ' ', ' '],
       [' ', ' ', ' ']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Comment: I've seen few, if any references to `chararray` on SO.   `dtype='S...'` is common.  And I've recommended the `np.char` functions on occasion.

Comment: @hpaulj I looked into the documentation on 'S' type protocol and in the scipy documentation it says "Note that `str` refers to either null terminated bytes or unicode strings depending on the Python version. In code targeting both Python 2 and 3 `U` or `np.unicode_` should be used as a dtype for strings. See [Note on string types](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#string-dtype-note).

Comment: I suppose it depends whether you want zero-terminated bytes (`a` or `S`), or use actual bytes (`b`), or actual strings (`U`).

Comment: I don't think there's a difference in how the data is stored, just a difference in how it is displayed.  `char_array2.tobytes()` and `char_array2.view(np.ndarray)` show that the spaces are there in the databuffer.

Comment: I see.  You're right. `char_array2.nbytes` and `char_array3.nbytes` are both 9. Not sure what the documentation means then by "For backward compatibility with Python 2 the `'S'` and `'a'` typestrings remain zero-terminated bytes".

Answer (score 0):

Just create your array with `ndarray`:

```
chararray = np.ndarray((3,3), dtype='S1')
chararray[:]=' '
```

gives:

```
array([[' ', ' ', ' '],
   [' ', ' ', ' '],
   [' ', ' ', ' ']], 
  dtype='|S1')
```